# MinGW Error "Only Win32 target is supported"

Tags: c, mingw-w64

I recently updated my Ubuntu and now I get an error message saying "In included file: Only Win32 target is supported" every time I try to compile a C project. I use Codelite 15.0.2 and Mingw-w64 7.0.0-2. Before I updated my OS everything worked flawlessly and I have no idea how to fix this error, reinstalling Codelite and Mingw-w64 and searching on google didn't solve anything either :(
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you share previous and current version of installed Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

MinGW-w64 exists for 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.
The `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32` part of the message you get tells me you're using the 32-bit Windows target.

If you run `apt-cache search mingw-w64` in Ubuntu you will see there are seperate i686 and x86-64 packages.